# function inside the cuda kernel

Tags: cuda

Is there any ways i can have a function inside cuda kernel. I mean my cuda kernel gets pretty long and hard to debug at one point. Thanks.

Answer (score 40):

yes, just mark function with `__device__` and it will be callable only from GPU. Check CUDA Programming guide, section B.1 
[Here is the direct link](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#function-declaration-specifiers)

Comment: Thanks for the information. The direct link is in: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-function-qualifier

Comment: And how about nested calls of several levels? Do we need to mark all those functions with __device__ ?